# How to change the text generated by <!--more--> Tag

Tags: read-more

I've looked and looked, I've read the codex, and tired several things to change this but nothing has worked. I don't know how to indicate what text to use for the  Tag

I have a theme that is using some custom code for displaying a single post on the blog page. The theme options allow you to show full content or excerpt. I have excerpt selected.

This is the code from the idex.php template file. I've looked for any references of "more" in fuctions.php or any other file for that matter but haven't found any.

```
<div class="post-content">
            <?php
            if($data['content_length'] == 'Excerpt') {
                $stripped_content = strip_shortcodes( tf_content( $data['excerpt_length_blog'] ) );
                echo $stripped_content; 
            } else {
                the_content('');
            }
            ?>
</div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: in your case, this might be part of the function `tf_content()` (?) - what theme are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's the first parameter to `the_content()`.

```
the_content('Read some more of this post');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_content

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time to change it your have to hook into [excerpt_more](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_more) :

```
function new_excerpt_more( $more ) {
return 'new text';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more')
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this on all my themes. This will add a permalink to the the "more" text . You can also add div and style it accordingly. Hope this helps

```
function more_excerpt($more) {
       global $post;
  return '&nbsp; &nbsp;><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> Change Read more text here</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'more_excerpt');
```